# How to add large number of users to muc room in ejabberd?

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-api, ejabberd-hooks

We have a requirement to **add 100k users to a single muc room** in ejabberd server. We are using **subscribe_room api** to add users one by one. While adding users to the muc room, memory consumed by ejabberd is getting increased. At some point, the Ejabberd server was consuming 11GB of memory. Since memory consumption keeps on increasing, the **Ejabberd server process is getting killed by the kernel**. We are using the ejabberd-21.01 version.

1. Do we need to change any configuration or are we missing anything?
2. Is there a way to add multiple users to muc room in a single api call to ejabberd?

Comment: As you should have noticed already, rest of the world doesn't use Indian words lakh / lac. So please don't use them here.

Answer (score 0):

> We have a requirement to add 1lakh users to a single muc room in
> ejabberd server.

I don't know what 1 lakh is, but anyway:

XEP-0045 MUC is designed for a few users chatting, or a few hundreds... not for thousands or millions of bots receiving notifications. Bots don't care about presence, so using MUC is overkill.

You should check alternatives, for example:

- ejabberd's MUC/Sub (it is a simplification of MUC suited for large amounts of subscribers
  https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/xmpp-clients-bots/extensions/muc-sub/
- XEP-0060 Publish-Subscribe, implemented in ejabberd's mod_pubsub

Comment: We have a school with more than 100k users & we want to send school level messages to all users. So We want to add all of them to a single muc room using ejabberd server. While adding 100k users, We got memory issue. Is there a way to add them in bulk without any memory issues?

Comment: To send school level messages to all users, see mod_announce
https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/modules/#mod-announce